# Why do I get warning CA2229 (Implement serialization constructors) when inheriting from standard type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I have a class definition like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDictionary: Dictionary<string, object>
{
}
```

However, I get this Code Analysis warning:

> CA2229 Implement serialization constructors
>   Add a constructor to TcpFieldValueDictionary with the following signature:
>   'protected TcpFieldValueDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)'.

However, the generic dictionary already has the constructor, only with a `public` modifier.

It is easy to add this constructor (see below), but why should this be done? What is the advantage?

```
    protected MyDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    { }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructors aren't inherited. It doesn't matter what constructors your base type has - if you want a constructor with a particular signature for your class, you have to implement one.

Otherwise, you just get the default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this (Call me Foon_The_Unbeliever apparently)

Comment: @Foon - you can read it in the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) - Section 1.6.4 (Base Classes): "Inheritance means that a class implicitly contains all members of its base class, **except for the instance and static constructors** ..." (My emphasis)